# Error failed to expand the variable

Tags: openmodelica

I have a model to read a file and do some operation on it and print the output in to a file. I got an error which I'm unable resolve it. The below code shows the declaration and assignment of the input data to an 2d array.

```
Real Data_2D[:,:]"data from input file as 2D matrix";
 length := Streams.countLines(Infile)"length of the input file";

  /*collect the data from input file in to 2D matrix */
    for i in 1:length loop
        currentLine := Streams.readLine(Infile, indexDataStart+i-1);
        nextIndex := 1;
        for j in 1:noColumns loop
            (Data_2D[i,j],nextIndex) := Strings.scanReal(currentLine, startIndex=nextIndex,unsigned=false, message="readCoefficientsHawc2.mo c[i,j] : Real scan not successful");
        end for;
    end for;
```

I got the following error "Failed to expand the vairable Data_2D"

It would be verymuch helpful if I get a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modelica tools in general do not like unknown dimensions during compilation. Modelica Specification says that all arrays sizes should be known at compile time.

In your case Data_2D has unknown dimensions. Also, from your code I don't see what type of component is length and Data_2D. Are they parameters, constants?

In your case it might be possible to use Modelica.Blocks.Tables.CombiTable2D to read the table from file.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer. I figured it out soon. Now, I have other issue. I got an error "DAE has 0 scalars and 0 equations". Could you please help me in this.